# Drupal JSON API how to include path_alias of relationship data?

Tags: json-api, drupal-9

I'm trying to include the path_alias information of related fields in a JSON:API request

I've tried this:

`http://localhost:8080/jsonapi/node/publication/xxxx?include=field_slices&fields[node--publication]=uid,uri,title,path_alias`

but no luck, I don't quite understand how the 'fields' parameter works tbh.

I've had some luck with the following request, this gets extra text details for a slices field in a different content type:

`http://localhost:8080/jsonapi/node/page/xxxx?include=field_slices.field_accordion_item`

but I can't figure out how to apply this to getting the alias from a related item, any pointers would be very much appreciated